# tagging words using lookup, what's the best approach?

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have some strings I want to test to see if they contain specific words. The words in question are in a lookup node, and if there is a match the word in the string needs to be tagged. I have a script that works almost ok, but I want to know if I'm using the best format, as I believe it's rather resource consuming, and not very foolproof.

Example xml :

```
<Main>
<NTUS>
    <NTU>match</NTU>
    <NTU>test</NTU>
</NTUS>
<Folder id="update">
    <about>This content is not in a span so we ignore it completely, even if we would have a match</about>
    <Title>
        <span class="string simple" lang="en">Some test content containing a single match</span>
    </Title>
    <Content>
        <span class="string complex" lang="en">Also keywords in sub elements should <strong>pass the test</strong>, and match.</span>
    </Content>
</Folder>
</Main>
```

My current xslt :

```
    <xsl:param name="units">
    <xsl:copy-of select="//NTU"/>
</xsl:param>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="NTUS"/>

<xsl:template match="text()[ancestor::span]">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\s+">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:variable name="theWord" select="."/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$units/*[text()=$theWord]">
                    <ntu>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </ntu>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

results in following :

```
<Main>
<Folder id="update">
    <about>This content is not in a span so we ignore it completely, even if we would have a match</about>
    <Title>
        <span class="string simple" lang="en">Some <ntu>test</ntu> content containing a single <ntu>match</ntu></span>
    </Title>
    <Content>
        <span class="string complex" lang="en">Also keywords in sub elements should <strong>pass the <ntu>test</ntu></strong>, and match.</span>
    </Content>
</Folder>
</Main>
```

Which is almost ok apart from the last node, as the [match] is at the end of the sentence and therefore not passing the regex. I can adjust it to make it match, but it could become pretty complex then, so i want to know if there are better ways to address this problem.

EDIT : there seems to be a small misbehaviour when you use a comma delimited list (might be on other occasions also, but this one I noticed)...

So for instance following xml

```
<Main>
<NTUS>
    <NTU>OPTION1</NTU>
    <NTU>OPTION2</NTU>
    <NTU>OPTION3</NTU>
    <NTU>OPTION4</NTU>
    <NTU>OPTION5</NTU>
</NTUS>
<local xml:lang="en">
    <span>Test string containing some comma seperarated lookup values: OPTION1, OPTION2, OPTION3, OPTION4, OPTION5</span>
</local>
```

Returns following when the script is applied :

```
<span>Test string containing some comma seperarated lookup values: <ntu>OPTION1</ntu>, OPTION2, <ntu>OPTION3</ntu>, OPTION4, <ntu>OPTION5</ntu></span>
```

so every second match is skipped. Any idea what is causing this behaviour ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vPatterns" select=
 "string-join(/*/NTUS/*, '|')"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="span//text()">
  <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex=
   "(^|(\P{{L}})+)({$vPatterns})($|(\P{{L}})+)">
    <xsl:non-matching-substring><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:non-matching-substring>
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
      <ntu><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(3)"/></ntu>
      <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(4)"/>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to the provided XML document:**

```
<Main>
<NTUS>
    <NTU>match</NTU>
    <NTU>test</NTU>
</NTUS>
<Folder id="update">
    <about>This content is not in a span so we ignore it completely, even if we would have a match</about>
    <Title>
        <span class="string simple" lang="en">Some test content containing a single match</span>
    </Title>
    <Content>
        <span class="string complex" lang="en">Also keywords in sub elements should <strong>pass the test</strong>, and match.</span>
    </Content>
</Folder>
</Main>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<Main>
    <NTUS>
        <NTU>match</NTU>
        <NTU>test</NTU>
    </NTUS>
    <Folder id="update">
        <about>This content is not in a span so we ignore it completely, even if we would have a match</about>
        <Title>
            <span class="string simple" lang="en">Some <ntu>test</ntu> content containing a testmatch or a single <ntu>match</ntu></span>
        </Title>
        <Content>
            <span class="string complex" lang="en">Also keywords in sub elements should <strong>pass the <ntu>test</ntu></strong>, and <ntu>match</ntu>.</span>
        </Content>
    </Folder>
</Main>
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitre, I will have to tweak it a bit further in case my lookup values contain characters that need to be escaped but this get's me started in the right direction at least

Comment: Actually there seems to be a little bug in the regex, but I can't figure it out. I've added an example in the original post, it's a pretty strange thing as there seems to be no logic behind it

Comment: @Wokoman, In the initial question you haven't specified what characters can appear in a pattern -- this is why I used a character class for any *letter* . Now we see that you also want digits. Use this: `(^|([^A-Za-z0-9])+)({$vPatterns})($|([^A-Za-z0-9])+?)`

Comment: Ah, I see. I was mislead by the fact that some of the matches worked, even if they included digits. I wasn't familiar with the \P{L} part of the original regex.